# How can I subtract the seconds from a timestamp which is double?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to subtract any seconds from a timestamp in `Cell(1, 1)`, the type of which is `Double`.

Here's the function I'm imagining:

```
Function subtractSeconds()

Dim timeStamp As Double
Dim timeStampSeconds As Double

timeStamp = Cells(1, 1)
'timeStampSeconds = getSeconds(timeStamp)

'Cells(1, 1) = timeStamp - timeStampSeconds

End Function
```

Here's what I have so far, with help of [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428426/how-can-i-subtract-the-seconds-from-a-timestamp-which-is-double#comment47027444_29428426). I am of course, looking for something more elegant:

```
Function subtractSeconds()

Dim timeStamp As Double
Dim timeStampHours As Long
Dim timeStampMinutes As Long
Dim timeStampSeconds As Long    

timeStamp = Cells(1, 1)

Cells(1, 1) = Format(Cells(1, 1), "yyyy/m/d hh:mm:ss")
timeStampHours = DatePart("h", Cells(1, 1))
timeStampMinutes = DatePart("m", Cells(1, 1))
'timeStampSeconds = DatePart("s", Cells(1, 1))

'something like the following to put the date time back together without seconds
'Cells(1, 1) = Format(Cells(1, 1), "yyyy/m/d") & TimeValue(timeStampHours & ":" & timeStampMinutes & ":" & 0))

'Convert back to double

End Function
```

Comment: Look up the function `DartPart` which allows you to extract any part of a DateTime including seconds.

Comment: `DatePart`? Looks very promising! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to `Format()` your `Cells(1, 1)`, then it contains a valid VBA date that just happens to be formatted as a number for presentation.

At which point you need

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = DateAdd("s", -DatePart("s", Cells(1, 1).Value), Cells(1, 1).Value)
```

This however will change the appearance of the number in the cell to a date even though it will still be stored as a number. If you want to keep the number appearance, use [`Value2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx):

```
Cells(1, 1).Value2 = DateAdd("s", -DatePart("s", Cells(1, 1).Value2), Cells(1, 1).Value2)
```

Comment: Brilliant. So many useful functions here I didn't know about. I will test it as soon as I get back to the drawing board. I actually prefer the number to be formatted as a date, but `Value2` seems really useful.